# filter through combobox in angular

Tags: angularjs

I have a select that is used as part of a filter for a ngtable:

```
                      <select  ng-model="eventsortOrder" >
                                <option value="All" selected>none</option>
                                <option value="Active" >Active</option>
                                <option value="Inactive">Inactive</option>
                       </select>
```

The table and filters look like this in html:

```
                 <tr ng-repeat="event in eventcategories.data |filter:eventsortOrder">
                                    <td>{{ event.name }}</td>
                                    <td>{{event.status }} </td>
                 </tr>
```

But data is not filtering properly..Thanks in advance.

Comment: firstly your filter is apply only one field  or all or each every have own filter

Comment: and your code into your filter apply on your all field because of you did not specified to filter for which field

Comment: @vijayPatel Thanks for your reply..Actually i need to Sort Based on status ,but it is working when i select "Inactive" and if i select "Active" it is displaying all

Comment: Ok ! i am putting your solution

Comment: Either according my suggestion this filter is not good because of you need change you value of option because both have 'Active' text available so, it's not making proper filtering

Comment: So, According my suggestion you need to make custom filter for it

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code !! I Hope useful....

```js
    var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

    app.filter('myfilter',function($filter){      
       return function( items, filter) {
    var filtered = [];
    angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
      if(filter===null|| filter == item.status || filter == 'All') {
        filtered.push(item);
      }
    });
    return filtered;
  };         
      return filtered;
    });

    app.controller('myController',function($scope){
      
    $scope.eventcategories={
    data : [{name:'First',status:"Active"},       {name:'Second',status:"InActive"}]
    };
    $scope.eventsortOrder=null;
      
    });
```

```html
    <html ng-app="myApp">
      <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body ng-controller="myController">  
      <select ng-model="query">
          <option value="All" selected>none</option>
          <option value="Active" >Active</option>
          <option value="InActive">Inactive</option>
       </select>    
       <table>
           <tr ng-repeat="event in eventcategories.data | myfilter:query">
    <td>{{event.name }}</td>
    <td>{{event.status}} </td>
    </tr>
          </table>
        </body>
      </html>
```